# What is the best way to center text in the Safari Browser

Tags: css

I am using CSS to place an overlay color over an image. Everything works fine in IE, Opera, Chrome and Firefox. The only difficulty that I am having in Safari is that the text that appears when the overlay displays refuses to center properly in the Safari Browser (5.1.7 - Windows). Below is the code just for the text portion of CSS code. Let me know if you need more to work with.

```
.text {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left:auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -moz-center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    margin-right:auto;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Comment: A basic view of your HTML would be usefull. How is your .text related to your image? Are the parent/child or siblings?

Comment: If width is 100% how is it going to be centered?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code is missing -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); Does adding this still produce an issue?